# Java Buffer to string array

Tags: java

I am reading a line by buffer reader in java.
Line is:
abc   3.8229  1.0326       1       1  1.1386   1.006

How can I store each word of this line in a string array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  import java.io.*;
   class Record
  {
  String name;
  String s1;
  String s2;
  String s3;
  String s4;
   String s5;
  String s6;

  public Record(String name, String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4, String s5,    String s6){
   this.name = name;
   this.s1 = s1;
   this.s2 = s2;
   this.s3 = s3;
   this.s4 = s4;
   this.s5 = s5;
   this.s6 = s6;
```

}

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
  try{
   FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String strLine;
      while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  String[] tokens = str.split(" ");
  Record record = new    Record(tokens[0],tokens[1],tokens[2],tokens[3],tokens[4],tokens[5],tokens[6]);//process  record , etc

 }
 in.close();
  }catch (Exception e){
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
 }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have

```
String var = "abc 3.8229 1.0326 1 1 1.1386 1.006";
```

You could produce a String array using [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String[] arr = var.split(" ");
```

This would produce an array `arr` containing each word of `var`.

Answer (score 3):

```
BufferReader br;
...
String line = br.readLine();
String[] words = line.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a Scanner.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
while( sc.hasNext() ){
    String word = sc.next(); // Get word
}
```

On the plus side of this you can also use the convenient methods of

```
double x = sc.nextDouble();
int i = sc.nextInt();
```

[And its ilk.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#method_summary)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the words while you are reading from the buffer :

```
    try {
        String line  = "abc 3.8229 1.0326 1 1 1.1386 1.006";
        List newWordSymbols = Arrays.asList(' ','\n','\r');


        StringReader sr = new StringReader(line);
        List wordList = new ArrayList();
        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
        int ch;
        while (( ch=sr.read())!=-1) {     
            char c = (char)ch;

            if(newWordSymbols.contains(c)){
                wordList.add(word.toString());

                word= new StringBuilder();
            }else{
                word.append(c);
            }

        }
        wordList.add(word.toString());


        System.out.println("Word list ::: "+wordList);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```